# Rails 5.2 /products/new.html.erb having real problems adding product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

OK, I have asked regarding a similar issue, but this is a problem with the views.  I have played with form_for for several hours and cannot quite get it right.  Wondering if anyone can point out obvioius mistakes...

/products/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Product</h1>

<%= form_for :product, as: :post, url: category_product_path(:product) do |form| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= form.label :name %>
   <%= form.text_field :name %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
   <%= form.label :category_id %>
   <%= form.text_field :category_id %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
 <% end %>


 <%= link_to 'Back', category_products_path %>
```

and my routes.rb:

```
category_products GET    /categories/:category_id  /products(.:format)                                              products#index
                      POST   /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)                                              products#create
 new_category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/new(.:format)                                          products#new
 edit_category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/:id/edit(.:format)                                     products#edit
     category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#show
                      PATCH  /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#update
                      PUT    /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#update
                      DELETE /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#destroy
           categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                                                    categories#index
                      POST   /categories(.:format)                                                                    categories#create
         new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                                                                categories#new
        edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           categories#edit
             category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#show
                      PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update
                      PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update
                      DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#destroy
```

and the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :category_id=>:product, :controller=>"products"}, missing required keys: [:id])
```

isn't column :id created when the migration occurs - I have a typical migration file with t.string :name and t.text :description, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `form_for` url is wrong. You should be using the route that points to `products#create`, which also has the `POST` verb that is used in forms

```
<%= form_for :product, as: :post, url: category_products_path do |form| %>
```

Comment: Thank you, its just the routes are very similar and typos easy to make, thank you.